# Rake 10.0.4 not found in sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I've just pushed a new Rails app from my local development machine to a server I have that has a few Rails apps already on, bundle installs everything correctly and rake tasks run fine, however when I try and start the app it fails with that message.

I've:

- Trashed my Gemfile.lock and reran `bundle install`
- Done `gem install rake` to get the latest version
- Checked `rake --version` shows 10.0.4.
- Checked `bundle show rake` shows 10.0.4
- Restarted the server

Now I'm drawing a blank on what it could be. Using Phusion Passenger, rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.2p290. I use rvm for managing the environment, but I've not changed anything with it for a long, long while now. The other Rails apps are all working okay without any issues, with similar gem dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self fixed, but not sure why. I ran `bundle install rake` by accident, forgetting it doesn't do what I think and it created a `./rake` folder which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your application is [being run as the wrong user](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_caveats_amp_troubleshooting).

Comment: I'd not come across that, but it shows as the same user as ones that are successfully running.